# Different apex:chart colors

Tags: visualforce-charting

How to get the different colors instead of just blue as shown below?

```
<apex:page controller="OppsController">
    <apex:chart data="{!Opportunities}" width="600" height="400">
        <apex:axis type="Category" position="left" fields="Name" title="Opportunities"/>
        <apex:axis type="Numeric" position="bottom" fields="Amount" title="Amount"/>
        <apex:barSeries orientation="horizontal" axis="bottom" 
            xField="Name" yField="Amount"/>
    </apex:chart>
    <apex:dataTable value="{!Opportunities}" var="opp">
        <apex:column headerValue="Opportunity" value="{!opp.name}"/>
        <apex:column headerValue="Amount" value="{!opp.amount}"/>
    </apex:dataTable>
</apex:page>
```

[image]

[source code:](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_charting_overview_providing_data_controller_method.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<apex:barSeries>` supports colorSet and colorsProgressWithinSeries attributes. By using them you could get different colors. As in your code:

```
<apex:chart data="{!Opportunities}" width="600" height="400" colorSet="#156F9E,#FF9123,#6BAE4A,#424242,#A4A4A4">
    <apex:axis type="Category" position="left" fields="Name" title="Opportunities"/>
    <apex:axis type="Numeric" position="bottom" fields="Amount" title="Amount"/>
    <apex:barSeries orientation="horizontal" axis="bottom" 
        xField="Name" yField="Amount" colorsProgressWithinSeries="true"/>
</apex:chart>
```

And the below image is what I have achieved in my chart: 
[image]

Comment: instead of hard-coding can the system generate by itself?

Comment: @NickKahn No. I don't think there is